A certain number of consecutive multiples of 6 make a sum of 546.
The original question talks about a seating arrangement of people sitting around a circular table facing the center. Everyone is sitting at distances of consecutive multiples of 6. The circumference of the table is 546. Is there any quick way or tricks to find out the starting multiple of 6 and/or number of people sitting around the table?
The distance is measured around the able. And, say, A,B,C,D,E are sitting around the table, then the distance between A and B is 24cm, B and C is 30cm, C and D is 36cm, and D and E is 42cm. The distances are consecutive multiples of 6 between each immediate pair.

I'm not sure I understand what's going on here. Is the distance measured around the table, or across the table? If the former, then why don't we just divide everything by $6$, and just say there's a table with $91$ seats, and we're putting people at some sequence of consecutive integer distances? It might be a good idea to just type the original question in.

The distance is measured around the able. And, say, A,B,C,D,E are sitting around the table, then the distance between A and B is 24cm, B and C is 30cm, C and D is 36cm, and D and E is 42cm. The distances are consecutive multiples of 6 between each immediate pair.

What @BrianTung says. Then if you look at any list of triangular numbers the answer is staring you in the face.

We can express the problem as finding positive integers $n$ and $k$ such that
$6(n + (n+1) + (n+2) + \ldots (n+k-1)) = 546 = 6\times 13 \times 7$.  This means solving for $kn + \frac{(k-1)k}{2} = k(n + (k-1)/2) = 13 \times 7$.  This gives
$(k=7, n=10)$ and $(k=13, n=1)$ as the only two possible solutions; i.e., there are $k$ consecutive multiples of $6$ (starting with the first multiple as $n \times 6$) that sum up to $546$.

You want to find positive integers $n$ and $m$ such that $n<m$ and $6n+6(n+1)+\cdots +6(m-1)+6m=546$. We may also not that the number $k$ of people is $k=m-n+1$.
The summands on the left hand side are from an arithmetic sequence with first term $6n$, last term $6m$, step size $6$, and a total of $k$ terms. You should be able to find an expression for the sum on the left in terms of these (or some of these) values. From there, you should be able to arrive in some equation involving $n$ and $m$ (or perhaps preferably, $n$ and $k$), which allows only very few choices.
